# Split string with dot as delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am wondering if I am going about splitting a string on a `.` the right way? My code is:

```
String[] fn = filename.split(".");
return fn[0];
```

I only need the first part of the string, that's why I return the first item. I ask because I noticed in the API that `.` means any character, so now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

`split()` accepts a regular expression, so you need to escape `.` to not consider it as a regex meta character. Here's an example :

```
String[] fn = filename.split("\\."); 
return fn[0];
```

Comment: In this case, you must use two backslashes. Apparantly, the `split()` method requires the use of two backslashes due to the fact that it is a method that interprets a String type, which in itself refers to a literal dot. [reference: Pshemo's solution]

Answer (score 24):

<sup>I see only solutions here but no full explanation of the problem so I decided to post this answer</sup>

### Problem

You need to know few things about `text.split(delim)`. `split` method:

1. accepts as argument ***regular expression*** (regex) which describes delimiter on which we want to split,
2. if `delim` exists at end of `text` like in `a,b,c,,` (where delimiter is `,`) `split` at first will create array like `["a" "b" "c" "" ""]` but since in most cases we don't really need these trailing empty strings it also removes them automatically for us. So it creates *another array without these trailing empty strings and returns it*.

You also need to know that [dot `.`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) is [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) in *regex*. It represents ***any character*** (except line separators but this can be changed with `Pattern.DOTALL` flag).

So for string like `"abc"` if we split on `"."` `split` method will

1. create array like `["" "" "" ""]`,
2. but since this array contains only empty strings and they all are trailing they will be removed (like shown in previous second point)

which means we will get as result empty array `[]` (with no elements, not even empty string), so we can't use `fn[0]` because there is no index 0.

### Solution

To solve this problem you simply need to create regex which will represents dot. To do so we need to escape that `.`. There are few ways to do it, but simplest is probably by using `\` (which in String needs to be written as `"\\"` because `\` is also special there and requires another `\` to be escaped).

So solution to your problem may look like

```
String[] fn = filename.split("\\.");
```

**Bonus**

You can also use other ways to escape that dot like

- using character class `split("[.]")`
- wrapping it in *quote* `split("\\Q.\\E")`
- using proper Pattern instance with `Pattern.LITERAL` flag
- or simply use `split(Pattern.quote("."))` and let regex do escaping for you.

Comment: this.. I really like the:

```split("[.]")```

Answer (score 17):

Split uses regular expressions, where '.' is a special character meaning anything. You need to escape it if you actually want it to match the '.' character:

```
String[] fn = filename.split("\\.");
```

(one '\' to escape the '.' in the regular expression, and the other to escape the first one in the Java string)

Also I wouldn't suggest returning fn[0] since if you have a file named `something.blabla.txt`, which is a valid name you won't be returning the actual file name. Instead I think it's better if you use:

```
int idx = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
return filename.subString(0, idx);
```

Comment: The question is tagged Java, not Javascript, which is what you linked to.

Answer (score 15):

the String#split(String) method uses regular expressions.
In regular expressions, the "." character means "any character".
You can avoid this behavior by either escaping the "."

```
filename.split("\\.");
```

or telling the split method to split at at a character class:

```
filename.split("[.]");
```

Character classes are collections of characters. You could write

```
filename.split("[-.;ld7]");
```

and filename would be split at every "-", ".", ";", "l", "d" or "7". Inside character classes, the "." is not a special character ("metacharacter").

Comment: @MisterSmith You might want to take a look at the programming language here. We're talking about java, not javascript.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was tired yesterday, having being coding in both languages, didn't notice the Java datatypes. I thought perhaps the answers were correct back in 2010 but somehow the browsers today behaved in a different manner.

Answer (score 7):

As DOT( . ) is considered as a special character and split method of String expects a regular expression you need to do like this -

```
String[] fn = filename.split("\\.");
return fn[0];
```

In java the special characters need to be escaped with a "\" but since "\" is also a special character in Java, you need to escape it again with another "\" !

Answer (score 5):

```
String str="1.2.3";
String[] cats = str.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be more efficient to use

```
 filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf("."))
```

if you only want what's up to the first dot?

Answer (score 2):

Usually its NOT a good idea to unmask it by hand. There is a method in the Pattern class for this task:

```
java.util.regex
static String quote(String s)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is the following

```java
String[] fn = filename.split("[.]");
```

Answer (score 1):

The split must be taking regex as a an argument...  Simply change `"."` to `"\\."`

Answer (score 0):

Note: Further care should be taken with this snippet, even after the dot is escaped!

If filename is just the string ".", then fn will still end up to be of 0 length and fn[0] will still throw an exception!

This is, because if the pattern matches at least once, then split will **discard all trailing empty strings** (thus also the one *before* the dot!) from the array, leaving an empty array to be returned.

Comment: easiest solution in cases like the one at hand is to also pass a limit-argument of 2 to the call to split:
String[] fn = filename.split("[.]",2);

Answer (score 0):

Using **ApacheCommons** it's simplest:

```
File file = ...
FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName());
```

Note, it also extracts a filename from full path.

Answer (score -3):

`split` takes a regex as argument. So you should pass `"\."` instead of `"."` because `"."` is a metacharacter in regex.

Comment: It must be "\\." not "\."