# Splitting a string in Java after adding a delimiter

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I've written some code which utilizes the split() method to return the first item delimited by periods.  After a little testing I found that the array I split the string into has a length of 0 so I assume it's not splitting at all.  It may be relevant that in some cases there is no period and I want the entire string returned.  To compensate for this, I added a period onto the end of each String.  See below:

```
longText=longText+".";
String tempName[]=longText.split(".");
String realName=tempName[0];
System.out.println(realName); 
return realName;
```

Comment: The string that it seems to get stuck on is "Full Issue PDF Volume 1, Issue 2".  Without the quotes of course.  I believe it's also the first string in the series to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method String#split takes a regular expression as an argument. See [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29%20Java%20Doc)

The following: [Split String on dot . as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387622/split-string-on-as-delimiter) will help you