# java String split, empty Array

Tags: java, string, split

I try to split the String "1.1" to 2 new Strings:

```
String[] array = "1.1".split(".");
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

but I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Why?

Comment: This was asked so many times. For example check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387622/split-string-on-as-delimiter).

Comment: Fullstop is a special character in regex. So use `"1.1".split("\\.")`.

Comment: BTW, i suggest `"1.1".split(Pattern.quote("."))` for these cases, to improve readability.

Comment: To add something to the useful answers: In fact the split first results in 4 matches, each one being an empty string. The dot matches **any character**, so the split finds the empty string in front of the first "1", then the empty string between the "1" and the ".", and so on. But according the [method's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), trailing empty strings are **not included** in the resulting array. So the resulting string array itself is of length 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` takes a regular expression. The dot character `.` is used to match any character in regular expressions so the array will be empty unless the character itself is escaped

```
String[] array = "1.1".split("\\.");
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what the dot character is used for (even though it is used here by accident)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape dot.

```
String[] array = "1.1".split("\\.");
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

If you look into [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) you'll find that split method accepts regex.

In regular expressions  `.` mean any Character except new line.

```
public String[] split(String regex) {
        return split(regex, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `. with \\`  so that it is not taken as a regex meta character as split takes a regular expression. You may try like this:

```
String[] array = "1.1".split("\\.");
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try String[] array =  "1.1".split("\\.");

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `"1.1".split("\\.")`