# How to convert dot (.) separated string into array list?

Tags: java, arrays, string

In my application I need to convert dot separated string to arraylist. I have seen in many places split function of string is used to separate comma separated  string to Array List.I studied in the documentation split function requires expression for splitting.In my case I provided dot and it is not converting.Am I missing something? Please help me.Below is my code I am using

Here,

```
 groupHierarchy.levelPrefix = 4201.4202;
 ArrayList<String> levelPrefixList = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(groupHierarchy.levelPrefix.split(".")));
```

When I log this it shows

```
Log.e("tracking","level prefix list is "+ levelPrefixList);
```

Comment: as split method expects a regular expression so you must use \\ ( double slash) to say you need to match .(dot)

Answer (score 3):

Use following:

```
groupHierarchy.levelPrefix.split("\\.")
```

[public String[] split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) use regex, so you have to escape "."

See [Split String on . as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387622/split-string-on-as-delimiter) for more details.