# Making an array out of a String and than making it in String one by one

Tags: java, arrays, string, minecraft-forge

I'm making a minecraft-forge mod and I'm having problems putting an String into Block#getBlockFromName(String name). the String:

```
String oreName = "minecraft:iron_ore -replace:minecraft:stone.minecraft:netherrack.minecraft:end_stone;";
```

And like you see after -replace: I have an block name (minecraft:stone) and a dot and than again block name and a dot. I want to split each block name into a separate String and read it one by one so I can insert it into Block#getBlockFromName and get 1 block out of each String. I tried using String#split(".") to split it into an array, but when I print out the array when I switched it back to String by using Arrays#toString it was empty. I want to split it by dots because I have an config file so those blocks can be changed to anything, I can't just pull out minecraft:stone out of the String because the ones who are using my mod will be able to configure that minecraft:stone to something else and add another block name by using a dot after the first block name.
This is what I've done so far:

```
String oreName = "minecraft:iron_ore -replace:minecraft:stone.minecraft:netherrack.minecraft:end_stone;";

    String block1 = oreName.substring(oreName.indexOf("-replace:"));
    String block2 = block1.replace("-replace:", "");
    String block3 = block2.contains(" -") ? block2.substring(0, block2.indexOf(" ")) : block2.replace(";", "");
    System.out.println("The Block Names Are: " + block3); // It prints it just without "minecraft:iron_ore -replace:" and ";" at the end
    String[] block4 = block3.split(".");
    System.out.println("The array: " + Arrays.toString(block4)); // only prints out "The array: []"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split String on dot . as delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387622/split-string-on-dot-as-delimiter)

Comment: Problem almost entirely due to the duplicate older question. Also, dot is probably not a good delimiter anyway. As soon as a mod block comes along with a name like, say, `mymod:ores.copper` your system falls apart. `;`, `!`, or `|` would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `String.split()` takes regular expression as argument.
For your case you need to escape `.` symbol with:

```
String[] block4 = block3.split("\\.");
```

Which prints

```
The array: [minecraft:stone, minecraft:netherrack, minecraft:end_stone]
```

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, flag it as a duplicate. Don't *answer* it.