# java split dont work with regex "DOT" ("DOT" because stackoverflow does not accept dots)

Tags: java, split

I want to split a String with the regex ".", but the result is strange

```java
String position = test.image.png;
String[] split = position.split(".");

System.out.println(position);
System.out.println(split.length);
for(String element : split) System.out.println(element);
```

WHY the output is:

```
test.image.png
0
```

???

Comment: What is `test.image.png` here ? and to split by `.` you need to escape like  `position.split("\\.")`

Comment: Does this  answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with dot as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387622/split-string-with-dot-as-delimiter)

Answer (score 2):

```
String position = "test.image.png";
String[] split = position.split("\\.");

System.out.println(position);
System.out.println(split.length);
for(String element : split) System.out.println(element);
```

The code above will work. Why? Because you need to escape metacharacters in Java Regex with a backslash. A `.` (fullstop/period) is such a character. Using it without an escape, will **match any character**.

[More info on Java Regex](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/index.html#:%7E:text=To%20escape%20a%20metacharacter%20you,%5C.)

Be sure to take a look at the provided link, everything's in there and easily understandable.

Comment: Well, you have to escape dots for the regex, and escape the backslash you use to escape that. Dots are not special characters in Java strings

Comment: As I understood it, there are several metacharacters that need to be escaped. A point is  one of them...

Comment: Yes, but my point was that your answer makes it seem like you're always supposed to escape dots in Java strings, even though the first backslash is for regex and the *second* backslash is to escape that first one. (By first backslash, I mean the one closer to the dot)

Comment: yes, you're correct. If you know it, it seems so simple. I'll edit the answer

Comment: That's very good of you. Could you also add that it is `.` that is a metacharacter and say what the dot does in regex normally?

Comment: as per request. It's oft forgotten how much the small things matter, such as providing a thorough answer. I need to keep that in mind, so thank you.