# Scala how to use regex on endsWith?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to figure out how to isolate all file extensions from a list of file names using regex and `endsWith`.

So as an example

input:
file.txt, notepad.exe

output:
txt, exe

What my idea is, is to use `filter` to get file names that `endsWith("."_)`. But `endsWith("."_)` doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the actual code you have tried, an mwe. Please provide the output of your code and explain how that differs to the output you would like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You really do not want to `filter`, you want to map each filename into its extension.
*(and maybe then `collect` only the ones that had an extension and probably you only want each unique extension)*

You can use a regex for that.

```
object ExtExtractor {
  val ExtRegex = """.*\.(\w+)?""".r
  
  def apply(data: List[String]): Set[String] =
    data.iterator.collect {
      case ExtRegex(ext) => ext.toLowerCase
    }.toSet
}
```

You can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/FChrXV1HQ9eCNLu4BJ8Q0w).

Answer (score -1):

how about using split('.') which will return a

```
String[] parts = fileName.split("\\.");
String extension = parts[parts.length-1];
```

Comment: this does not work at all, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387622/split-string-with-dot-as-delimiter. also the second line will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Yup i see.. the array out of bound it would have to be length -1